# OpenCV Knn Match ERROR

Tags: opencv, image-processing, error-handling, knn, feature-detection

So I have written some code to compute the raw matches between two sets of features using the knnMatch function in opencv. The code has been running fine but produces this error for certain images.

> error: (-215) _queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescType in function cv::BFMatcher::knnMatchImpl

This is the line that produces the error.

```
rawMatches = matcher.knnMatch(featuresA, featuresB, 2)
```

I was just wondering if anyone has any ideas what might be causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I could observe that it happend when `featuresB` (the '`trainDescriptors`' Parameters is None or empty. So probably you should check if you have any descriptors in the variable `featuresB` before. (If not you don't have any matches)